# How to use 2 ui-grid with ng-hide and ng-grid?

Tags: html, angularjs, ng-show, ng-hide, ui-grid

I am new to angularjs and I want create one Page in which I want to add 2 ui-grid with one button called "other-grid" first time it must Load 1st grid and when we click again then 1st grid must replace with 2nd grid But some Problems are there I want to use ng-show and ng-hide it works for first grid but not loading 2nd grid Properly Why So and Any Solution Please..

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you give the 'other' hidden grid proper height and width so that the framework knows the grid dimensions

You can try using ng-if, ng-show, ng-hide and make the other grid visible when you click on the button - 'other grid'

Here is the official UI grid [tutorial](http://ui-grid.info/docs/#/tutorial/108_hidden_grids) which does something similar to what you want

Answer (score 0):

You are probably better off using ng-if when dealing with ui-grid.

As for ng-show, it does weird things when rendering ui-grids (refer to: https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-grid/issues/4559)

Here is plunker of 2 grids with a toogle button:
http://plnkr.co/edit/IGF6X7SqtFdFSk8jiory?p=preview

```
 <button ng-click="toggleuigrid()">toggle grid</button>
 <div class="row">
     <div class="span4" ng-if="show">
         <div id="grid1" ui-grid="gridOptions1" class="grid" ></div>
     </div>

    <div class="span4" ng-if="!show">
        <div id="grid2" ui-grid="gridOptions2" class="grid"  ></div>
    </div>
 </div>
```